# Escaping parentheses in Go regexp

Tags: regex, go

I am tying to run the following regular expression on a string in Go

`\(([0-9]+),([0-9.]+),(?:$([0-9]+))\)`

but I keep getting the error `unknown escape sequence: (`

the string that I'm running it on is `(1,53.38,$45) (2,88.62,$98) (3,78.48,$3) (4,72.30,$76) (5,30.18,$9) (6,46.34,$48)`

So my question is, how do you escape parentheses in Go's regexp?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes, because `\(` isn't a valid excape sequence.

```
"\\(([0-9]+),([0-9.]+),(?:$([0-9]+))\\)"
```

More commonly you would use backticks for string literals without escaping:

```
`\(([0-9]+),([0-9.]+),(?:$([0-9]+))\)`
```

Comment: Well don't I feel dumb haha. Thanks!