# Go exec.Command escaping chars

Tags: go, imagemagick

Go's `exec.Command` has this very weird way of receiving parameters.

I'm trying to execute a simple `ImageMagick` command but it fails due to how it interprets the strings I'm passing:

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("convert", "out.png", "-resize", "50%", "-respect-parentheses", "+write", "mpr:out", "\\(", "mpr:out", "-colorspace", "gray", "\\)", "null:")
    fmt.Println(cmd)

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
```

Running the code above I get the error:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/convert out.png -resize 50% -respect-parentheses +write mpr:out \( mpr:out -colorspace gray \) null:
convert: unable to open image '\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
convert: unable to open image '\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: unable to open image '\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
2021/01/01 22:56:57 cmd.Run() failed with exit status 1
exit status 1
```

The weird part is, if I copy and paste the printed command, it runs.
But for some reason, the string "\(" is misinterpreted.

Is there a way to make go compiler understand this command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35183194/13860

Comment: The syntax you are passing is the syntax you use with a shell. When you execute a program without a shell, you have to pass the arguments to the program however the shell will interpret them. So, either run your program through a shell, or pass arguments  correctly. If the things inside the parentheses are to be sent as a single argument, just pass (value value value) as a single string.

Comment: Hi, @Flimzy, thanks for your suggestion, but I have the same issue using back ticks instead of doulble quotes.

Comment: Hi, @BurakSerdar. I just tried that, but now the error is `unable to open image '\( mpr:out -colorspace gray \)'`

Comment: What is the command line you use to run this with a shell?

Comment: Hi @BurakSerdar, the one that is printed on the first line of the output: `convert out.png -resize 50% -respect-parentheses +write mpr:out \( mpr:out -colorspace gray \) null:` it runs with no issue on shell

Comment: `\(` produces `(` after shell processing. Just use `"("` and `")"` as arguments.

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar! That did the trick. It is weird that when I applied your first suggestion `(value value value)` it didn't work even without the slashes. But removing the slashes and keeping each string separated, it worked. If you want to write an answer for my question, I'd gladly mark it as solved :)

Comment: Because `(value value value)` passes that string as a single argument, but the application you are running is expecting each element, including the parentheses, as separate arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with Go specifically. When you execute a program using a shell, the shell parses the command line you entered and constructs the arguments for the program you want to run. When you run:

```
convert out.png -resize 50% -respect-parentheses +write mpr:out \( mpr:out -colorspace gray \) null:
```

the shell processes the argument list to construct an array of arguments containing `out.png`, `-resize`, `50%`, `-respect-parentheses`, `+write`, `mpr:out`, `(`,  `mpr:out`, `-colorspace`, `gray`, `)`, `null:`.

So you should not pass `"\\("`, but pass `(`. Same for the matching parenthesis.